# How Do I Sign with a PKCS8 Key In PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, private-key

Currently I have a pkcs8 formatted private key and am trying to use openssl to sign data.

My code is as follows:

```
    $data = "Data that I wsant to sign";

    $private_key ="
    -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIFLTBXBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wSjApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIlPwCxnroNJUCAggA
    MAwGCCqGSIb3DQIJBQAwHQYJYIZIAWUDBAEqBBDOK7DOSiWN/iSUIK1mfbZHBIIE
    0PFuTznnLXVEz+iECw/jq+6VQf/cpGQRVbEFppzoxo6JqTUC/hjZsh8+9bdCNSvf
    GsaTMixKvVgzi+9wF3tb0sTS2f8Qsd9acRsQ14e0qg4Efi2gUYcQKk+mZwzgwAFi
    wZZdTNa6I/lB5dZoAaShkvyPQWpvG7oPNg0igF+ZJ79czdBEsdk0LfDfn1djBrOR
    4+1fpD13ELkehG6VngEI26dkke6FKngVA9qlByNw6qzxh63Y5ftey3Gr4yJSjCm4
    WIHOdMO0d/G9DtqdCaJkiu0V+6MhFIkhVI8GWaelsU6L50Z3GQXTkax2rMfMCjAL
    gyNqRnMfQF0aGuMDreIsbJJyfPB118kcN4seqZwUFQ8v2XnU2bzZ46v/LIjm0EMT
    Oj6MUSTGYz0NEGVCwD914wEQQ+IvpZQUrKLZvus2eas/H9SImmIotaZGaR66cMK3
    ARGXLOGkamwmOWXaj5e4/Nqj1YPoyO1gCqLvqaifS3BKfe5emVQiFn37Yj2LUtFE
    gaTmW+S7QhGkfNfiT0ihUeVWFKneR5ZVQ4ZWHXamc7QwUbKOZqD6CHKWtwudBJ/A
    1BSC3geeKhND1XzAENtjOxwrNMbmtlBGgp/zOnaxNQE2J8x7ZWzGRAz1isXqOoXT
    KCatixh918u2U0YfaRBGyOLBK83UjcMsfRSYyowx/AwR4iET4gORG7hai+6Jcujk
    Jq2M1oJdlbtBzYoI9NGUsytiHz+BR6o/d3qqGaFobcbDzfQFhWQhprWBdq/Z5nsp
    GRyBJJx3LA+bIkXgfQyMvh7BwOZ7p6Irp2+7Oj4Gh6zBFH6312cGesXbzDIu8uTP
    m8UeWpNG8Oo3FB3xa/s7lm6+xFc8byXRSGxBx0akFBTI929Cjw4sscheodSYOXYo
    rNwfhTBsggSIOwoGdolMgidFDovS64UjoXl1NkSgivdtTfEjLQx6bMohkoBPnHJu
    V2yQiWllXKQ6TQyJfKQPILJUSXE4dKos5jLlduxSTy8hYDJ1W8TdB24axQf6RPlq
    hkESP9SuKRQojizY7ne/hn56NYkjcjekjS31qfa1JyHzkZTKJB5uqdQdzXi5iyZq
    mmjs4j1GOWfe2p8BMyPeE91h7EOGIKpJoCWLqdbU4gUKZb9kVrNenpxtd3lAoGAs
    AVujiANdQhndmrb6gDfaRh6rT9Cu2TQsk27YD1Nmb05ihYmWkXJlMe2hN6nhIkEy
    MSWCv+ZfuW3NSaBFRw1rCLEB1xfFnkmsBOmxgW6eJ0UxRONU2jQ8Hf233tJc1LaI
    JI+F1coi9VGq4dVBZ5nupw0MSVbgOJO7fnH7uP47Va1tq5YM0pB4tMib/KsKDwPk
    oDFMp/wfSs/Ctt5GJ7bzlcHUfQIEntzRDurdfPNSlsDk14KUudzQM+XK8HRPTaRA
    yICJBmgvNq9IrK0/bNDyZyNNwUw0TDJKuSa0aNTM9s9ksodrgCGGbouCnXipD6GZ
    aJtXy4I0rBSxh+EKtzkjHoD/Lik90NFlEPcASsQ9vFMVyOwbgMwZLtZ5nYhF9/bX
    dgG8VLoIGJ9sMpbA+OJUOvbW6cgrADWfIZbpjjCgDW4aGJjJIPYmxDwWlfbuWA6j
    0LLAp/Eqj68hoMEBGU6bYmIm8eHG+o1O3Df7ZkGudcEK
    -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----";
    
    $binary_signature = "";
    
    $algo = OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256;
    $pkey=openssl_get_privatekey( $private_key, 'password' );
    openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $pkey, $algo);
    $signature = base64_encode($binary_signature);
    echo $timestamp = time();
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($signature);exit;
```

However, I'm getting **openssl_sign(): Supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key** error

I can't seem to find any references that use pkcs8 formatted keys for signing data using PHP. Hoping someone could give me some insight into this.

Thank you

New version of the code (Still having the same error)

```
    $data = "Data that I want to sign";

    $private_key ="
    MIIFLTBXBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wSjApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIlPwCxnroNJUCAggA MAwGCCqGSIb3DQIJBQAwHQYJYIZIAWUDBAEqBBDOK7DOSiWN/iSUIK1mfbZHBIIE 0PFuTznnLXVEz+iECw/jq+6VQf/cpGQRVbEFppzoxo6JqTUC/hjZsh8+9bdCNSvf GsaTMixKvVgzi+9wF3tb0sTS2f8Qsd9acRsQ14e0qg4Efi2gUYcQKk+mZwzgwAFi wZZdTNa6I/lB5dZoAaShkvyPQWpvG7oPNg0igF+ZJ79czdBEsdk0LfDfn1djBrOR 4+1fpD13ELkehG6VngEI26dkke6FKngVA9qlByNw6qzxh63Y5ftey3Gr4yJSjCm4 WIHOdMO0d/G9DtqdCaJkiu0V+6MhFIkhVI8GWaelsU6L50Z3GQXTkax2rMfMCjAL gyNqRnMfQF0aGuMDreIsbJJyfPB118kcN4seqZwUFQ8v2XnU2bzZ46v/LIjm0EMT Oj6MUSTGYz0NEGVCwD914wEQQ+IvpZQUrKLZvus2eas/H9SImmIotaZGaR66cMK3 ARGXLOGkamwmOWXaj5e4/Nqj1YPoyO1gCqLvqaifS3BKfe5emVQiFn37Yj2LUtFE gaTmW+S7QhGkfNfiT0ihUeVWFKneR5ZVQ4ZWHXamc7QwUbKOZqD6CHKWtwudBJ/A 1BSC3geeKhND1XzAENtjOxwrNMbmtlBGgp/zOnaxNQE2J8x7ZWzGRAz1isXqOoXT KCatixh918u2U0YfaRBGyOLBK83UjcMsfRSYyowx/AwR4iET4gORG7hai+6Jcujk Jq2M1oJdlbtBzYoI9NGUsytiHz+BR6o/d3qqGaFobcbDzfQFhWQhprWBdq/Z5nsp GRyBJJx3LA+bIkXgfQyMvh7BwOZ7p6Irp2+7Oj4Gh6zBFH6312cGesXbzDIu8uTP m8UeWpNG8Oo3FB3xa/s7lm6+xFc8byXRSGxBx0akFBTI929Cjw4sscheodSYOXYo rNwfhTBsggSIOwoGdolMgidFDovS64UjoXl1NkSgivdtTfEjLQx6bMohkoBPnHJu V2yQiWllXKQ6TQyJfKQPILJUSXE4dKos5jLlduxSTy8hYDJ1W8TdB24axQf6RPlq hkESP9SuKRQojizY7ne/hn56NYkjcjekjS31qfa1JyHzkZTKJB5uqdQdzXi5iyZq mmjs4j1GOWfe2p8BMyPeE91h7EOGIKpJoCWLqdbU4gUKZb9kVrNenpxtd3lAoGAs AVujiANdQhndmrb6gDfaRh6rT9Cu2TQsk27YD1Nmb05ihYmWkXJlMe2hN6nhIkEy MSWCv+ZfuW3NSaBFRw1rCLEB1xfFnkmsBOmxgW6eJ0UxRONU2jQ8Hf233tJc1LaI JI+F1coi9VGq4dVBZ5nupw0MSVbgOJO7fnH7uP47Va1tq5YM0pB4tMib/KsKDwPk oDFMp/wfSs/Ctt5GJ7bzlcHUfQIEntzRDurdfPNSlsDk14KUudzQM+XK8HRPTaRA yICJBmgvNq9IrK0/bNDyZyNNwUw0TDJKuSa0aNTM9s9ksodrgCGGbouCnXipD6GZ aJtXy4I0rBSxh+EKtzkjHoD/Lik90NFlEPcASsQ9vFMVyOwbgMwZLtZ5nYhF9/bX dgG8VLoIGJ9sMpbA+OJUOvbW6cgrADWfIZbpjjCgDW4aGJjJIPYmxDwWlfbuWA6j 0LLAp/Eqj68hoMEBGU6bYmIm8eHG+o1O3Df7ZkGudcEK
    ";
    $key = wordwrap($private_key, 64, "\n", true);
    $key = <<<EOF
    -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
    $key
    -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
    EOF;
    $private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($key, 'password');
    openssl_private_encrypt($data, $encrypted_data, $private_key);
```

Comment: This is an encrypted key, so you need a password.

Comment: I have added a password $pkey=openssl_get_privatekey( $private_key, 'password');

But am still presented with the same error

Comment: Use heredoc string (<<<EOF) instead of double quote string, the whitespaces can cause the problem. If it still report the same error, check openssl version in phpinfo (1.1.1).

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me!. I have checked the openssl version in phpinfo SSL Version OpenSSL/1.1.1p. I have also updated my question with a new code base using EOF, still am presented with the same error

Comment: Please print `$key` and find out the problem.

Comment: Shingo, thank you. I have solved my issue by using get_file_content method instead. pkeyy_get_private returns true now
 
$private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents(storage_path('key.pem')), 'password');


I hope this answer will help anyone who faced the same issue as me :)